# PDF of a mixed exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving

> Problem. Beginning at time $t = O$. we start using bulbs. one at a time, to
> illuminate a room. Bulbs are replaced immediately upon failure. Each new bulb is
> selected independently by an equally likely choice between a type-A bulb and a type-B
> bulb. The lifetime, $X$, of any particular bulb of a particular type is a random variable,
> independent of everything else, with the following PDF:
>
> for type-A bulbs: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x}, & if\ x \ge 0, \\ 0, & otherwise; \end{cases}$$
> for type-B bulbs: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 3e^{-3x}, & if\ x \ge 0, \\ 0, & otherwise; \end{cases}$$
> Determine the PDF of the time until the
> 12th bulb failure.

Let $Z$ be a random variable denoting the time until the
12th bulb failure.

Possible solutions to calculate $PDF$ of $Z$,

1. First calculate $MGF$ and then deduce $PDF$. In this example, $MGF$ can be computed as $$ \left[\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-s} + \frac{3}{3-s}\right)\right]^{12}$$
   Deducing $PDF$ of $Z$ is a tedious task in this case.
2. Let $X_{i}$ be time between $i^{th}$ and $i+1^{th}$ failures, then $PDF$ of $X_{i}$ is $\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x} + 3e^{-3x})$. Then, $$Z = \sum_{i=1}^{12} X_{i}$$.
   If $X_{i}$ would have been purely exponential then $Z$ would have been easy to compute. But still using convolution $Z$ can be computed.

Confused, what is the correct line of thought? Any help is appretiated.